# Does $a_{n}$ have a cluster point?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I caught myself thinking about this:

Consider an arbitrary monotone sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ and that $\lim a_{n} = \pm\infty$. Does a sequence like this have a cluster point?

I really don't think so because, as far as I know, it won't have any convergent subsequences and, therefore, it won't have cluster points neither.

Am I wrong? How would I formalize this argument?

Thanks so much!

Comment: It would be great if you could also argue as to _why_ there are no convergent subsequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x$ is a cluster point. Then there is some index $N$ that for $n \ge N$ we have $|a_n| > |x| + 1$. So all but finitely terms are more than 1 away from $x$, so this can never be a cluster point of the sequence.

No monotonicity needed, just limit to plus or minus infinity.